# iphone / ObjC - Method to remove/add views based on arguments - possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multiview

I'm new - i'm sorry - but I'm experimenting with multiview iphone apps, and wondered whether the below idea was a) possible and b) sensible.

I want to create a method that can remove and add views based on some parameters - the outgoing view, the incoming view and the incoming class.

```
- (void)switchViews:(Class)inView:(Class)outView:(Class)inClass{

inClass *tempView = [[inClass alloc]
                     initWithNibName:@"inView" bundle:nil];


tempView.burgerViewController = self;   

self.inView = tempView;
[tempView release];


[outView.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view insertSubview:tempView.view atIndex:0];

}
```

This would be called by:

```
[burgerViewController switchViews:viewMainMenu:viewOptions:ViewMainMenu];
```

Any help is much appreciated - I have a lot to learn.

Mike.

Comment: I don't know in which context you will be using this, but if you are trying to simulate screens I think you would be better off using an existing controller designed to handle screens of content (e.g. UINavigationController).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, in that (it appears that) you've misunderstood how method names work in Objective-C.

For example, as your method currently stands, it is named:

```
switchViews:::
```

That's probably not what you're looking for.

A better name might be:

```
replaceView:forProperty:withViewOfClass:
```

Declared, that would look like:

```
- (void) replaceView:(UIView *)outView forProperty:(NSString *)propertyName withViewOfClass:(Class)inClass;
```

And you would use it like this:

```
Class viewOptions = ...;
NSString *viewMainMenu = @"...";
[burgerViewController replaceView:viewMainMenu forProperty:viewMainMenu withViewOfClass:viewOptions];
```

For more on Objective-C method names and interleaved arguments, check out the [Objective-C Programming Language Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW5).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your first problem is that you release tempView and then attempt to insert it into the view. Don't release tempView at all, just keep it as-is for insertion into the main view.